# What is this plant with white flowers in Albania

Tags: identification, flowers

I have photographed this flower, but I can not figure out what it is. Maybe someone can recognize it

[image: white flower]

I have photographed it in Fier, Albania.

Answer (score 3):

Looks like it might be Lobelia Erinus, specifically [this variety](https://www.rhs.org.uk/plants/310903/lobelia-erinus-fountain-white-(fountain-series)/details). Some research indicates it may be grown throughout Europe, including Albania (according to the conditions preferred on the site I link, and conditions throughout Europe).

[image]

[image]

Comment: Hello, we prefer it if the answers were complete.  There is nothing wrong with a reference.  Are you able to quote some text or post a photo from there ?

Comment: Hi Rohit, is my answer not complete? I have linked to a website containing what I feel is a fairly strong source. Could you indicate what criteria are used here for sources, or what else I would need to include? I have added the images from the source directly to the post if that helps. Thanks

Comment: website links can and do become stale, so it's helpful if you quote and credit relevant points so the answer does not become dead when the website goes 404: not found in a few years.

Comment: Understood, thanks for clarification!